# android LinearLayout.LayoutParams add new view

Tags: android

i need add a new button and textedit to my LinearLayout.. if I create a new param, the buttons are created over each other..

my mainactivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyTouchEventView tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
        setContentView(tv);
        addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
        addContentView(tv.btnSave, tv.params2); 
    }
```

and MyTouchEventView:

```
public class MyTouchEventView extends View {

    public Button btnReset;
    public Button btnSave;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2;

    public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        btnReset = new Button(context);
        btnReset.setText("Vymazat platno");

        btnSave = new Button(context);
        btnSave.setText("Ulozit");


        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);

        params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(40, 20, 40, 30);

        btnSave.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvY1T.png

Comment: Why you dont create using xml ? Its efficient than writing via code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a simple layout for your activity?

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="myText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="myText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);                   
}
```

Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html